# At a given distance from the origin, which convex subsets of an $\ell_p$-ball have the maximal volume?

Tags: geometric-probability, concentration-of-measure, minimal-surfaces

For a positive integer $n$ and  $p \in [1,\infty]$, let $\mathbb B_{n,p} := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid \|x\|_p \le 1\}$ be the $\ell_p$ unit-ball in $\mathbb R^n$. Fix $h \in [0, 1]$.

> **Question.** Of all **convex** subsets $A$ of $\mathbb B_{n,p}$ with $d(0,A) = h$, which shape maximizes the volume ?

**N.B.:** $d(0,A) := \inf_{a \in A}\|a\|_p$ is the distance of $A$ from the origin.

Intuitively, the answer to the above question for $p \in \{2,\infty\}$ should be **spherical caps**, i.e $A=\{x \in \mathbb B_{n,p} \mid x_1 \ge h\}$. I think the question should be solvable using isoperimetric inequalities (e.g Brunn-Minkowski), but I'm not sure how to proceed.

## Observation

Without the convexity constraint, a simple symmetry-based argument yields $vol(A) \le vol(Annulus(h,1)) = 1-h^2$ whenever $d(0,A)=h$, where
$$
Annulus(h,1) := \{x \in \mathbb R^n \mid h \le \|x\|_p \le 1\}
$$

Comment: I don't understand, any set (regardless of volume) that has $0$ in its closure will have minimal distance. There is no constraint on shape?

Comment: @copper.hat He says minimal distance. I guess that he actually wants $d(0,A):=\sup_{a\in A} \Vert a \Vert_p$. This would also match with the annulus maximizing the distance.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Thanks! Partly I am hoping the OP will clarify.

Comment: @copper.hat I hope so too. Thanks to you I realized that I did not read as carefully as I should have.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: I do that all the time :-).

Comment: @copper.hat I wanted to tell you for quite some time that the section about you is highly entertaining. I particularly like "If I see further than most, it is because I have stood on the toes of giants and they kicked me high into the air..." :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Thanks :-), it intended to be some self-deprecating humour but I think some folks interpret it in the opposite sense :-).

Comment: @copper.hat and Severin: Sorry for the confusion. The question as stated didn't make much sense. See reformulated question.

Comment: As the unit ball in the $p$-norm is convex, we get that set maximizing the volume under your constraint is the unit ball intersected with a half-space touching the ball of radius $h$ tangentially (for $p\notin \{1; \infty\}$, as for $p\in \{1;\infty\}$ the sphere is not smooth). It is not clear to me how we have to pick the half-space. One exception is the case $p=2$ as in this case everything is invariant under rotation and hence we can pick whatever half-space we like best that touches the ball of radius $h$.

Comment: Yes, the ball / half-space intersection you describe is precisely the spherical cap $\{x \in \mathbb B_{n,p} \mid x_1 \ge h\}$ I conjectured in my question. Indeed the case $p=2$ is trivial. The real deal are the cases $p \ne 2$.

Comment: I do not quite understand. What I describe is not the same as you wrote. Your half-space is very particular, I just said that it is of the form "intersection of the unit ball with a half-space". Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I answered taking $d(0, A):= \sup_{a\in A} \Vert a \Vert_p$. Otherwise, as pointed out in the comments by copper.hat, every set that contains the origin in its closure has zero distance.

The shape $A$ that minimizes the distance to the origin for a given volume is (up to sets of measure zero) a ball. This follows from the observation that if $A$ is not (up to sets of measure zero) a ball, then the ball with radius equal to the $d(0,A)$ has the same distance to the origin, but larger volume as $d(0,A)$ (as $A$ is contained in the ball of radius $d(0,A)$). Thus, I can shrink the radius to get the volume of $A$ and get smaller distance to the origin. However, then $A$ did not have minimal distance to the origin.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the original post. The question didn't make much sense. See edit. Upvoted your post post regardless (though it is now orphaned, w.r.t the question it tries to answer...)

Comment: That is nice of you. I'll think about the new version of the question.